# unable to upload images using rails paperclip and nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

Here is my form in view

```
<%= nested_form_for Post.new,html: {multipart: true},url: {action: :create} do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :title,placeholder: 'title' %>
<%= f.fields_for :post_detail do |uploads| %>
    <%= uploads.file_field :upload %>
<% end %>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
```

This is my `post.rb` model

```
has_many :post_details
accepts_nested_attributes_for :post_details
```

This is my `post_detail.rb` model

```
belongs_to :post
has_attached_file :upload
```

Here is my post_controller.rb

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params)
      @post.post_details.build
    if @post.save
      flash[:success] = 'Post added successfully'
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash[:error] = 'Post cannot add. Please try again after some time'
      redirect_to action: :new
    end
  end
```

**Edit 1**

This is the log i can see

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ZjAnCeF2F1tkDVni96GcihdCd5JkyXHPaTIBjKoLq4s=", "post"=>{"title"=>"test","post_detail"=>{"upload"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xb2e8208 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20130911-3059-1ahxfek>, @original_filename="Ubuntu-Wallpaper-HD.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"post[post_detail][upload]\"; filename=\"Ubuntu-Wallpaper-HD.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}}}
Unpermitted parameters: post_detail
Unpermitted parameters: post_detail
```

**Edit 2**

In rails 4 i used attr_accesible like this

```
private
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title,post_details_attributes:[:upload_file_name,:upload_file_size,:upload_content_type])
  end
```

**Edit 3**

I have manually added 3 column in post_details table

`upload_file_name,upload_file_size and upload_file_content`

only null inserted for the above 3 field and image not uploaded.

**Edit 4**

If i add `<%= f.fields_for :post_details do |uploads| %>` It is not displaying nested form itself

Comment: please check in console what error is showing. there may be typo error

Comment: @SabyasachiGhosh Can you please check my edit 1 in question for console log

Comment: i guess there is some whitelist attribute issue in post detail model or you can set att_accessable in the post detail model please check

Comment: are this new parameter are whitelist attributes or make them as  attribute_accessable

Comment: `attribute_accessible` no longer support in `rails 4`

Comment: yes i know that.. make it white list attributes. which is supported in rails.

Comment: I am not familiar with whitelist attributes. Where i can change it

Comment: please check the link
http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/strong-parameters-rails-4-countdown-to-2013

Answer (score 0):

This might not be your only problem but if you're using the `config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true` setting in your current environment, add this to your post.rb:

```
attr_accessible :post_detail_attributes
```

Another issue jumping out at me is that `@post.post_details.build` probably belongs in your new action rather than create.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
private
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title,post_details_attributes: [:id, :upload])
  end
```